# React Native Elements ListItem borderBottom Length Control

Tags: user-interface, react-native

I am trying to control the length of the BottomBorder on my ListItem, the listItem is rendered inside a List Component, going through the doc the only way i could found is through borderBottomStartRadius which is working and achieving the desired overall look. But it doesn't look perfect from UI point of view.

Here a snippet from my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Image,
    Text
} from 'react-native';
import {
    List,
    ListItem,
    Avatar,
    Header
} from 'react-native-elements';


class HomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Header
                    leftComponent={<Image source={require('../../../images/avtar_logo.png')} />}
                    centerComponent={{ text: 'DAWI', style: { color: '#fff', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '500', fontFamily: 'Roboto' } }}
                    rightComponent={{ icon: 'notifications', color: '#fff' }}
                    outerContainerStyles={{ backgroundColor: '#40beb3' }}
                    innerContainerStyles={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
                />
                <List containerStyle={{ marginTop: 0 }}>
                    {
                        Data.map((section, index) => (
                            <ListItem
                                title={
                                    <View style={styles.titleView}>
                                        <Text style={styles.titleText}>{section.title}</Text>
                                    </View>}
                                subtitle={
                                    <View style={styles.subtitleView}>
                                        <Text style={styles.subtitleText}>{section.subtitle}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                }
                                key={index}
                                avatar={<Avatar
                                    height={24}
                                    width={24}
                                    source={section.image}
                                    overlayContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: colors.whiteBackground }}
                                />}
                            />
                        ))
                    }
                </List>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

[How this look!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/decPq.png)

If one looked carefully on the left end of Border, it look distorted cause of the radius behavior. Is there any other means i can control the border length?!

**Update:**

**Raised an [issue](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/1282) on react-native-elements GitHub and look like there is no build in solution available at the time been, there is a work around using [ItemSeparatorComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#itemseparatorcomponent) prop from FlatList. If anyone could help implement this feature, please comment on the GitHub thread.**